# How to insert a 'String' in a 'JTextField' to a specific position?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I want to insert a `String` in a `JTextField`. Something like-

```
myTextField.insert(text, position);
```

How can it be done? Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may do this-

```
jTextField.setText("This  swing.");    
jTextField.getDocument().insertString(5, "is", null);
```

And `jTextField` will show-

> This is swing.