# Insert document (.doc) in TextArea java

Tags: java, swing, document

I want to insert document in my TextArea. How can I do it?

I found method setDocument(Document document), but I don't understand, how can I create variable of type Document.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;


/**
 * Created by Oleg on 18.04.14.
 */

public class MainForm extends JDialog implements ItemListener, ActionListener {

JPanel panel = new JPanel(/*new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,320,80)*/);

CheckboxGroup cbG = new CheckboxGroup();
Checkbox rap, punk, rock, drum;

JLabel label1, label2;

JTextArea textArea;

public MainForm() {
    setSize(640, 860);
    setTitle("Main");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(5,4);

    //setLayout(new BorderLayout(10,10));

    cbG = new CheckboxGroup();

    rap = new Checkbox("Rap", cbG, false);
    punk = new Checkbox("Punk", cbG, false);
    drum = new Checkbox("Drum", cbG, false);
    rock = new Checkbox("Rock", cbG, false);

    label1 = new JLabel("<html><font color='red'>Choose kind of music: </font></html>");
    label1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 25));

    label2 = new JLabel("asa");

    panel.setLayout(experimentLayout);
    panel.add(label1);
    panel.add(label2);
    panel.add(rap);
    panel.add(punk);
    panel.add(drum);
    panel.add(rock);
    panel.add(textArea);


    add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    rap.addItemListener(this);
    punk.addItemListener(this);
    drum.addItemListener(this);
    rock.addItemListener(this);
}

@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    repaint();


    //if(e.getItem().equals(punk.getLabel()))
        //textArea.setDocument(j);




}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}
```

I want to write a program that displays a Checkbox choice in a field TextArea document with information about the genre. There is an event that is responsible for selecting the flag and in the future it should load document in TextArea), but I can't load document..

Comment: post the rest of your code & explain what's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
    Document doc = new PlainDocument();
    SimpleAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    try {
        doc.insertString(0, "your content", set);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textArea.setDocument(doc);
```

camickr mentions you can also use:

```
    textArea.append("your content")
```

For `JTextField` check this link

[How to insert a 'String' in a 'JTextField' to a specific position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493508/void-insertstring-str-int-pos-for-a-jtextfield)

Comment: Can I insert a document?

Comment: In your case you can use insert(), or change the JTextArea to JTextField and use the method provided in the link. The difference between JTextArea and JTextField is whether it can support multiple lines. This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552708/whats-the-difference-between-jtextarea-and-jtextfield is a good example to illustrate the difference

Comment: Thanks), but if I'll use JTextField, how can I load the document?

Comment: @ZhangMeng, `JTextArea does not have setDocument()`, sure it does. the setDocument(...) method is found in the JTextComponent class. Also, the common way to add text to a JTextArea is to use the `append(...)` method.